# The most efficient way to submit documents to elasticsearch

Tags: api, submit, elasticsearch

elasticsearch has several APIs for submitting documents (http, thrift, memcached). What's the most efficient way to submit a document in terms of resources used?

My use case is about to have quite intensive flow of documents. And packing a file to a multipart form (instead of doing PUT) is kind of resource wasting. AFAIK thrift also reprocesses all the file to pack it to the thrift transport. May be memcached-like API is more efficient?

Comment: Maybe this is interesting too? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/bulk-udp/

Comment: How many documents you expect to index by second? How large? It seems a bit premature optimization. Most of ES users use HTTP or Java API (my case) and it seems to have good performance.

Comment: I expect 1Gbps taffic for indexing. In terms of averages it would be 30 5MB documents per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your case. There're at least 2 ways:

1. Do document extraction before search backend. Then do HTTP PUT. Save on traffic.
2. You can outsource data transfer to different mechanisms (NFS/HTTP PUT/FTP/whatever). After data is delivered it can be imported with [FS River](http://www.pilato.fr/fsriver/).